# Git commit to a custom parent

Tags: git, git-commit, magit

Example log-graph:

```
A B
|/
a
```

Wanted local(not pushed yet) workflow:

- if the commit `x` is needed just for the branch `A` - commit `x` into the branch `A`
- if the commit `x` is needed just for the branch `B` - commit `x` into the branch `B`
- if the commit `x` is needed for branches `A` **and** `B` - commit `x` **on-top** of the revision `a`, the most recent common ancestor of branches `A` and `B`

The last case should change the log-graph into this:

```
A B
|/
x
|
a
```

Whats the easiest way to accomplish such a workflow? (bonus if its in Emacs/Magit)

Comment: I don't understand your shorthand.  `A` and `B` are the tips of different branches?  Is `a` yet another branch?

Comment: @EdwardThomson `A` and `B` are the tips of different branches, `a` is just a revision/commit

Comment: You can't in any way alter the ancestry of a commit without rewriting it. checkout a, commit x, rebase x A, rebase x B.  There's no way to conceal the alteration from others, they'll have to refetch and rebase any of their own work.

Comment: @jthill I edited this line: *Wanted **local(not pushed yet)** workflow*

Answer (score 3):

Create a new branch based on `a`:

```
git checkout -b workbranch a
```

Make your changes and commit them:

```
...
git commit -m 'i made some changes'
```

Rebase `A` and `B` on your work branch:

```
git checkout A
git rebase workbranch
git checkout B
git rebase workbranch
```

Delete workbranch if you don't need it anymore:

```
git branch -D workbranch
```

Repeat as necessary.